# newton's cradle with 2 balls dropped from same height at same time

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, momentum

I'm creating a logo and want it to be as exact as possible.

The logo idea is a "Newtonian cradle", but with only 2 balls and on straight steel wire (can't be bend).

What would happen if I dropped these as in the image from the same height, at the same time ?

[image: Newton's cradle]

Comment: Provided the wire is rigid,the two balls will strictly fall vertically downwards under gravity till the wire becomes taut.

Comment: Yes, but if they were locked on a steel wire on that fixture point in the middle, which they could rotate around. Would they rotate down and work like newton's cradle, where they bump each other around, or would they simply stop?

Comment: For rotation, torque must be present.

Comment: I have tried to create an animation of how I think it would go down! www.designduck.dk/cph/newtons/sales-training.html

Comment: At any other position, it was imparted by the component of gravity. But at this position,torque becomes zero. Hence,they'll not rotate.

Comment: $\text{Torque} = r.F. \sin\theta$ . At this position, $\theta = \pi$ . So, torque becomes $0$.

Comment: @user36790 - $\theta$ is not $pi$. The balls would have to overlap for both to be straight up. It will fall, but slowly at first.

Comment: I'll try again. I'm an designer so don't have a lot of knowledge about physics, so all help is appreciated. But I have tried to create an animation of how I think it will react if they could rotate. Would this be possible? http://www.designduck.dk/cph/newtons/sales-training.html

Comment: Yes, this is indeed possible! Sorry for I was daydreaming with 1 ball. SHM will occur.

Comment: They 'll work like a cradle provided damping is absent or then you 'll have to consider Stokes' law.

Comment: @David Hammen: Sorry,sir for the mistake:-( . Yes, i was thinking about this when you posted the comment.

Comment: @Andreas Münter: Really sorry for the inconvenience. They'll work indeed!

Comment: @AndreasMünter - Your animation is a bit off. You have a nearly constant angular velocity. The balls will move rather slowly at the start. They'll pick up speed at an increasing rate as the balls get closer to horizontal, then pick up even more speed as the they fall through the horizontal and eventually collide.

Comment: @DavidHammen Yeah, I know. Working on that at the moment :-) But thanks for the info

Comment: @Andreas Münter: Definitely torque is the rotational counterpart of force. And so it will change the angular velocity $\omega$ . Hence,during the descend, the balls will accelerate as said by David Hammen. Best of luck for your work:)